# Running Zend site under Alias?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, wamp, alias

I want to run Zend site under an alias on WAMP. I am able to setup alias, but when I copy a working Zend site there and modify .htaccess to include "RewriteBase /alias", it still does not work. Error messages tell me that controller not found. Mainly this is what happen:

I have: server.com/alias
With Zend file structure inside (application, public, etc).

alias points to c:/wamp/apps/alias
Where Zend structure is stored.

.htaccess has line: RewriteBase /alias

As I understand server.com/alias should act as root folder, but it's not. If I run Zend site under root folder everything works fine then.

Can you tell me how to properly set up alias to run Zend site on WAMP? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your rewrite rules doesn't work well. take a look at [this](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/70).

Comment: I'm not sure what was the content of that link but here is another one: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter + http://blog.ryantan.net/2010/03/setting-up-wamp-for-zend-framework-projects/